# smbmount not working on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, smb, cifs

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 and I was trying to mount a folder to the Ubuntu system.
So I used:

```
sudo smbmount <folder> /path/to/my/folder -ouser=<my id>, dom=<my dom>
```

but the smbmount was not found...
All I have now is cifs-utils.

The command above works in Ubuntu 12.04, but not 12.10.

Any hints?

Thx in advance :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Run this :-

```
sudo apt-get install smbfs
```

In future if you have a command that you don't find, you can run

```
apt-file search smbmount
smbfs: usr/bin/smbmount
```

to search for the file that you need. Of course to install apt-file, you need

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update
```

Comment: Additional thnx for apt-file search!